# Eliminating time zone from date string in a Unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have date formatted like below and I want to remove GMT+05:30 from the date using a shell script.

```
Tue Dec  4 17:30:51 GMT+05:30 2012
```

and output should be

```
Tue Dec  4 17:30:51 2012
```

I am new to shell script and still learning.

Comment: do `man date` at the prompt - the date command has a ton of date formatting options.

Comment: Where do the extra 24 days come from?

Comment: I mean same format. Though I got it. Many thanks to members.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` if you can't change the `date` output:

```
... | sed 's/GMT+5:30 //g' | ...
```

But a better solution is to use `date` formatting capabilities:

```
date +"%a %b %d %T %Y"
```

(for details, see [`man date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date))